# Replace Text Inside An Iframe With An Image

Tags: jquery, blogger

I'm trying to replace the "Sign Out" text with an image that is in an iframe(the comments section).

I have tried several things, but I think this is the closest to being correct:

```
$("#comment-editor").contents().find("Sign out").html("<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sJ_cc0hh_jw/TtllFIQ-NSI/AAAAAAAAEM4/zJdS8K9rjZ4/s1600/index.gif" alt="Sign out" />");
```

`#comment-editor` is the ID of the iframe. "Sign Out" is the text I want to replace, although it's immediate HTML structure looks like this:

```
<span id="signoutLink">
    <span id="commentDash" style="display: none;">–</span>
    <a target="_top" href="http://xxxxxx.blogspot.com/logout?d=http://www.blogger.com/logout-redirect.g?blogID%3D4240883138904129005%26postID%3D3175710312324737334">Sign out</a>
</span>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Probably trying to get around the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: you won't be able to alter content if the iframe source is not from the same domain - demo -  http://fiddle.jshell.net/s9p7a/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<span id="signoutLink">
<span id="commentDash">–</span>
<a target="_top" href="http://xxxxxx.blogspot.com/logout?d=http://www.blogger.com/logout-redirect.g?blogID%3D4240883138904129005%26postID%3D3175710312324737334" id="anchor" >Sign out</a>
```

```
$("#anchor").text('').html('<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sJ_cc0hh_jw/TtllFIQ-NSI/AAAAAAAAEM4/zJdS8K9rjZ4/s1600/index.gif" alt="Sign out" />');
```

I added an id to the anchor tag, cleared it's text and then added html to it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6nQP/14/

Comment: if you for some reason don't want to add an id to the anchor tag,
`$("#signoutLink a").text('').html('<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-sJ_cc0hh_jw/TtllFIQ-NSI/AAAAAAAAEM4/zJdS8K9rjZ4/s1600/index.gif" alt="Sign out" />');`

will also do the trick